# Create and Plot Time Series Data in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a (1x700) vector x for which I would like to create and plot a time series object in Matlab. Each observation corresponds to one month, and the first observation belongs to January 1960. I tried the following:

```
state1 = timeseries(x,1:size(x,2));

state1.Name = 'Test';
state1.TimeInfo.Units = 'months';
state1.TimeInfo.StartDate = 'Jan-1960';     % Set start date.
state1.TimeInfo.Format = 'yy';         % Set format for display on x-axis.
state1.Time = state1.time - state1.time(1);      % Express time relative to the start date.

plot(state1);
```

However, I still see numbers on the x-axis instead of years. Could anyone please help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 'Months' is not a valid TimeInfo unit

Comment: Are  you looking for a way to plot months using a datetime label for the x axis?

Comment: @krisdestruction Thanks for your help. I simply want the x-axis to show years, for my data which is monthly. I don't know exactly if that is what you mean? I don't know about datetime labels but I thought the timeseries class could do that.

Comment: Years as in "1960" or years as in "Jan-1-1960"? Does each entry correspond to a year?

Comment: @krisdestruction I have 12 observations for each year. It doesn't really matter to which day in the month they correspond, as I just want to show the years only on the x-axis. (i.e. I have a January 1960, February 1960 etc.)

Comment: Let me know if that solves it for you!

Comment: @krisdestruction Trying it out now :)! Thanks for your help in any case!

Comment: If it works, kindly accept it. If it doesn't, please clarify what went wrong and I'll fix my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create random data. `1/12` corresponds to the fraction of a year that each month represents.

```
x = 1960:1/12:1970;
y = rand(1,121);
```

Then plot the x and y axes data using `plot`.

```
plot( x, y )
```

Then set the tick as follows for a decade per year. 1960:1970 will generate [1960 1961 ...] each corresponding to the tick's year.

```
set( gca, 'XTick', 1960:1970 );
```

Here is the output plot.

[image]

Doing 1 year intervals get **VERY MESSY** with lots of data. So solutions include doing a larger interval or setting your ticks to display vertically instead of horizontally. This code below shows how to set 5 year intervals instead.

```
set( gca, 'XTick', 1960:5:2010 );
```

Comment: Thanks, it does what it should :)! Appreciate your help!

Comment: There still seems to be a bit of an issue with the labels on the axis. When I try other configurations for other years, often even though I have for instance `set( gca, 'XTickLabel', 1960:2010 );` and I have the correct number of observations, it shows only labels up to and including 1967.

Comment: Can you update a screenshot of this into your question? As well with the code that you tried using this answer?

Comment: I added it to the OP now, together with the code that I used.

Comment: @dreamer Sorry had a quick bug. It's 'XTick' instead of 'XTickLabel' :)

Comment: The output for so many ticks might get messy, so you might need to rotate the years to a vertical alignment

Comment: Thanks again :)!  This works but it is rather messy indeed. Would there otherwise be an easy way to only show the years every 5 or 10 years?

Comment: You get what you ask for XD Yeah just specify a 5 year interval as follows: `1960:5:2010`

Comment: Haha, true :P! Thanks again, that solved all the remaining issues :)! Appreciate it!

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly too. No problem :)